# Bind XAML property indirectly

Tags: wpf, binding, indirection

Imagine, I have a button and a binding:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=FailOverStrings.ConfigTestBtn, Source={StaticResource    ResourceWrapper}}></Button>
```

Now I want to setup an array of such buttons:

```
        <Grid >
            <ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Button Content="{Binding Title}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
```

I will create a collection in the code behind but how to say that 'Title' which is equal to 'ConfigTestBtn' is not really a string 'ConfigTestBtn' itself but is a name of a property of FailOverStrings ?

Some kind of an indirection in binding.
I suppose I can write a converter to do it, but is it really necessary?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, post your `ViewModel` code

Comment: You say "an array of such button".. but there is no "such button" in your Grid's code.. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Imagine that somewhere in the code there's an array of such strings "ConfigTestBtn", "ConfigSipBtn" e.t.c. I want to show them in the grid. But the strings itself are just a properties in some resource container.

So, I don't want to show titles as "ConfigTestBtn" when displaying a grid of buttons. I want title to be shown as in first example - as a  value of property of some reosource object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a class like below.

```
public class FailOverStrings
{
    public FailOverStrings()
    {
        ConfigTestBtn = "Actual value";
    }

    public string ConfigTestBtn { get; set; }
}
```

Then your converter can look like this

```
public class PropertNameToValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string retValue = string.Empty;
        FailOverStrings settings = new FailOverStrings();
        foreach(PropertyInfo pinfo in settings.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (pinfo.Name == value.ToString())
            {
                retValue = pinfo.GetValue(settings, null).ToString();
            }
        }
        return retValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And using this converter in button like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:PropertNameToValueConverter x:Key="PropertNameToValueConverter"></local:PropertNameToValueConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=PropertyName, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=PropertNameToValueConverter}}" Width="100" Height="30" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. I also thought about this solution but it looks like a bit complicated. So, there's no way to do it directly in XAML ?